# How to match a field in the middle or the end of a line with separators?

Tags: regex, pcre, separator

Sorry for this title, I don't know how to explain my problem in one sentence.

I'm trying to match a field in a log but I don't know if it's in the middle of the line or at the end of it.

Example with three lines:

```
B=this is a short sentence C=see you soon A=hello world
C=see you soon B=this is a short sentence A=hello world
A=hello world B=this is a short sentence C=see you soon
```

I'd like to get the value of the "C" field (see you soon).
My problem is the last line, as there is no separator at the end of the string.

This is what I tried.

This one doesn't match the last line as it's the last field:

```
C=([^=]+) \w+=
```

This one works but looks over-complicated:

```
C=([^=]+)(?: \w+=|$)
```

How would you do this?

Comment: If it works for you, what answer do you expect?

Comment: Yes. Your answer is correct. Sometimes instructions have to be complicated to cover all the corner and edge cases. Also, use `+?` instead of `+`. Otherwise it won't work in the second case.

Comment: Also, what language? Java?

Comment: Sometimes things work but you feel like there's something better to do, or a short method you don't already know about...

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, just PCRE

Comment: From the SO regex tag: "Remember to include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't understand why I should use +? could you please explain ? :)

Comment: Referring to @Kobi's comment on the answer I just deleted, you don't. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You regex is already fine, I would have simplified the beginning:

```
C=.*?($|\n|(\w=))
```

You can try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/oN8cS2/1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see a potential bottleneck with the beginning: `C=` will also match `AC=`, thus I'd use a word boundary `\b` there.

I do not think you really intend to match a part of the next option, so I'd use a look-ahead rather than a non-capturing group (`(?: \w+=)`).

```
\bC=(.+?)(?=$|\s+[A-Z]=)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR4wL8/1)

Here, `.+?` will match 1 or more characters up to the end of string or 1 or more whitespace and an uppercase `A-Z` letter followed by `=`.

In case there can be any Unicode letters, you may replace `[A-Z]` with `\p{Lu}`.